# Как очистить память в Си. (Утечка памяти)

Tags: c

```
char *getSubstring(char *string, int position, int length)
{
   char *pointer;
   int c;
   pointer = malloc(length+1);

   if (pointer == NULL)
   {
      printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   for (c = 0 ; c < position -1 ; c++)
      string++;

   for (c = 0 ; c < length ; c++)
   {
      *(pointer+c) = *string;
      string++;
   }

   *(pointer+c) = '\0';
   return pointer;
}
```

В мне сказали, что в  этой функции происходит утечка памяти, поскольку она динамически выделяет буфер подстроки, но он нигде не освобождается. Расскажите как тут устранить утечку памяти. Я же должен вернуть результат, значит до этого вызывать `free(pointer)` нельзя.

Википедия: [Утечка памяти](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8).

**UPD**. Точнее сказать, при вызове этой функции происходит утечка памяти.

Эта функция вызывается внутри другой функции. Вот кусок кода:

```
char *func(int param)
{
  /* Тут вычисляются значения Y, jm, len */
  return getSubstring(Y, jm-len+1, len);
}
```

Вопрос тот же - как пофиксить? Тут ведь тоже очищать память нельзя! Это получается проблема моей структуры программы?

```
i=0;
  while (other_dna != NULL)
  {
    /* ... */
    myvar = func(/* ... */);
    /* используем myvar  */
    /* ... */
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: @Dezza  Simpson, все правильно, если бы функция возвращала внутреннюю переменную, то она бы в сближайшем времени затиралась. Задача по освобождению памяти лежит не на этой функции, а на том коде, который эту функцию вызывает.

Comment: @Fike: Спасибо. Я раньше вообще не знал об утечках памяти. Дописал всё нужное в вопрос. Расскажите как это исправить

Comment: @Dezza  Simpson, func является просто оберткой и передает строку дальше, я ничего не могу сказать.

Comment: @Fike: Дописал нужное в вопрос

Comment: while (other_dna != NULL)
    {
      /* ... */
      myvar = func(/* ... */);
      /* используем myvar  */
      /* ... */
      free(myvar); // закончили использовать - сразу очистили
      i++;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вместо цикла

```
for (c = 0 ; c < position -1 ; c++)
  string++;
```

можно было просто написать string += position - 1;

Во-вторых, мне не нравится сам факт, что выделение памяти происходит внутри функции, а её освобождение - вовне. Я бы переписал так:

```
char* getSubstring(const char* str, int pos, size_t len, char* substr)
{
    str += pos - 1;
    strncpy(substr, str, len);
    *(substr + len) = '\0';
    return substr;
}
```

А выделение и освобождение памяти перенёс бы во внешнюю функцию. В Вашем случае func.

В-третьих, если уж Вам позарез нужны динамические строки (очень хорошо подумайте, может, всё-таки можно заменить статическими, пусть и потребуется выделить сразу много памяти?), напишите свой фреймворк для работы с ними. За образец можно взять код из [CuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 2):

[[@Dezza  Simpson](/users/18483/dezza-simpson)](/users/18483/dezza-simpson), нет тут никакой утечки. Просто вызывающий код должен учитывать, что возвращаемый из `func()` результат размещен в памяти, выделенной `malloc()`.

Обычно такие подробности обязательно должны присутствовать в описании функции (даже если пишете для себя).

--

Если подходить к задаче, не как к тренировке, то вместо `getSubstring()` можно использовать библиотечную (по крайней мере в *nix) функцию `strndup` (см. `man strndup`)

У Вас будет

```
 char *func() {
   ...
   return strndup(Y + jm - len + 1, len);
 }
```

--

Вообще, я бы добавил, что это (возврат динамической памяти в том или ином виде и ее освобождение в другом месте) достаточно распространенная практика и не стоит опасаться ее использовать (хотя более традиционный (академический) подход к проектированию приветствует проводить выделение/освобождение ресурсов на одном уровне).

Просто немного внимания к деталям программы и все будет ОК.